# Getting connection issue on the server for Heroku Redis Addon

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, node-redis, heroku-redis

I have deployed my express.js backend server to Heroku, and I am using Heroku Redis Addon.
I used redis 5.0.17 previously, but removed it recently and created new addon with version 7.0.
After that I have updated the redis config in my codebase based on the guidance of heroku documentation, and it is working well on my local development environment when I tried to connect to the heroku redis addon from my local server. But after deploying my backend codebase to the server, I am getting following error:
`Error accepting a client connection: error: 1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

It seems like it is because of the redis npm module version of my codebase because I am using old version - 3.0.2, but not sure why it is working on local, but not working after deploying.

Comment: I have upgraded my redis npm version to 4.0, but still getting the same error